# saving big image with actual size in matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I am currently working with a  RGB image with 2112X2816 pixels dimensions in matlab. Since the image is quite big, the actual image is shown at 33%. I have performed image processing on this image and I want to save it to the similar size as actual image.
unfortunately, when I am getting getframe and saving it with imwrite, the saved image size is changing. I have also tried to use the set option to redefine the 'Position' of the image, but the same problem exist, there. Can anybody suggest me some solution?

Comment: Did you put annotations or non-image stuff?  That is to say, was there something in your image beyond the "I" in "image(I)"?  If so then just saving the matrix "I" to an image isn't going to help.  Please clarify what you did, in general terms, so that an answer will be as informative as possible.

Comment: I have perfromed some segmentation operation, generated mask and separated my region of interest. Since the separated regions are small in resolution, I need to save them as the same size. Basically, I am performing the same operations for all available images in my hand to check the robustness of algorithm. Hence, it would be nice that the program automatically saves all the output image at same size so that I can see the possible bugs

Comment: Could you save them as multiple images?  You could zero-pad, then have several segments - but if you have 1000 subsets it could get prohibitive for space/time/manageability.  You could save the segments as recolored variations on the same matrix-image.  That would preserve the information unless the segments are not independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not save the figure, save the actual 2112x2816x3 image array using imwrite.

Failing that, save the figure using `export_fig -a1 -native test.png`. [Export_fig](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-exportfig) can be downloaded from the MATLAB file exchange.